# Why won't the Launchy gem work in Shoesrb?

Tags: ruby, shoes

I can't seem to get the button to open the url in a browser. The script runs in Shoes, however the button does not do anything. What am I doing wrong?

```
Shoes.setup do
  gem 'launchy'
end

require 'launchy'

Shoes.app do
    background "#EFC"
    border("#BE8",
           strokewidth: 6)

    stack(margin: 12) do
      para "Enter ID"
      flow do
        @e = edit_line

        id = @e.text

        fburl = "http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id="

        #alert fburl+id

        button "OK" do
        Launchy.open("#{fburl}+#{id}")



      end
    end
  end
end
```

After making the suggested changes and using "shoes.setup do", I get the following error:

undefined method 'dir for Gem:Module :344:in 'method_missing'    C:/Program Files (x86)/Common Files/Shoes/O.r1514/ruby/lib/rubygems/installer.rb:97:in 'initialize' C:/Program Files (x86)/Common Files/Shoes/O.r1514/lib/shoes/setup.rb:265:in 'new' C:/Program Files (x86)/Common Files/Shoes/O.r1514/lib/shoes/setup.rb:265:in 'install_sources' C:/Program Files (x86)/Common Files/Shoes/O.r1514/lib/shoes/setup.rb:27:in 'init C:/Program Files (x86)/Common Files/Shoes/O.r1514/lib/shoes/setup.rb:329:in '' C:/Program Files (x86)/Common Files/Shoes/O.r1514/lib/shoes.rb:105:in 'require' C:/Program Files (x86)/Common Files/Shoes/O.r1514/lib/shoes.rb:105:in 'setup' Shoes Gem Loader.rb:1:in '' C:/Program Files (x86)/Common Files/Shoes/O.r1514/lib/shoes.rb:428:in 'eval' C:/Program Files (x86)/Common Files/Shoes/O.r1514/lib/shoes.rb:428:in 'visit' C:/Program Files (x86)/Common Files/Shoes/O.r1514/lib/shoes.rb:118:in 'show_selector C:/Program Files (x86)/Common Files/Shoes/O.r1514/lib/shoes.rb:151:in 'block (4 levels in splash' (null):0:in 'call'

Am I to assume that launchy is not a usable gem in Shoes?

Comment: I haven't been able to reproduce this error. I added `gem 'addressable'` (launchy's dependency) before `gem 'launchy'` however I got error about undefined Encoding::UTF_8. Try this, and tell us if you have the same error. What you get after changing this? ps. when this error appeared (clicking button, before click etc)

Comment: I've made the changes you suggested, but I still get exactly the same error. The error occurs when I open Shoes and click "open an app". I've also noticed that that this error does not seem to be specific to launchy, I get the same problem even when I run this script, with any other gem: http://pastebin.com/4fjgBc0q

Comment: It must be problem with Shoes itself. If you click some element of Shoes' gui and it sends errors it means something is wrong with Shoes, not with gems you have not yet installed. I have random errors with my installation too. You can try reinstall it or use *Green shoes*. It is gem - you can install it via: `gem install green_shoes`. It should install all dependencies but they takes few hundreds of MB as fair I remember.

Comment: Darek, many thanks for the for suggestion about using Green Shoes. This is perfect, switched over to using it, and the script runs perfectly. Much appreciated for the help you gave me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "original" Shoes doesn't play well with gems. The newest version of Shoes (Shoes 4) lets you require gems normally. It's pre-alpha, but almost feature-complete. Here's your code modified to run in Shoes 4. Note that the `id` assignment has to be moved into the button block (but this would be necessary for any version of Shoes)

```
require 'launchy'

Shoes.app do
  background "#EFC"
  border("#BE8", strokewidth: 6)

  stack(margin: 12) do
    para "Enter ID"
    flow do
      @e = edit_line

      fburl = "http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id="

      button "OK" do
        id = @e.text
        alert fburl+id
        Launchy.open("#{fburl}+#{id}")
      end
    end
  end
end
```

To install Shoes 4, follow the [instructions on GitHub](https://github.com/shoes/shoes4/blob/master/README.md#installing-shoes4-from-github), and make sure you `gem install launchy`. Then you should be able to [run your app](https://github.com/shoes/shoes4/blob/master/README.md#running-a-shoes-app).

Answer (score 0):

It's because Red shoes is has different (independent) Ruby installation so gems are in the different folder.

In order to use gems you should do this:

```
Shoes.setup do
  gem 'launchy'
end
```

ps. it still may not work if gem you are using is not compatible, as fair I remember, with Ruby 1.9.1.
Red shoes is using this version on my computer. I'm not sure about other operating systems though.